# Amplifier damage caused by failed power supply capacitors

Tags: power-supply, amplifier

**MY QUESTION IS THIS:
Would failed power supply caps cause peripheral damage to the amp, preamp or control circuits ? Supposedly there is "protection" for "DC offset, over current and over heat"**

I have a Proton AM-656 amplifier with "Dynamic Power on Demand" which is a second higher voltage supply rail (switched to when needed) that creates 6db of headroom and 2 ohm stable. I did not think there was fault protection, turns out the schematic block diagram states there is.

One day with the amp power on I tightened/snugged up the speaker binding post. There was a single frayed speaker wire (unnoticed) that shorted. The amp proceed to billow smoke. I looked inside to find several power supply caps having oozed their electrolyte onto the circuit board.

I am shopping to recap two of my other amps and was thinking of recapping the Proton, however I do not want to waste my time if there is likely to be damage to the circuits other than electrolytic capacitors.

Comment: It seems unlikely that several capacitors would fail at once, perhaps you could post a photo. It may be something else entirely that you are seeing.

Comment: A poorly designed amplifier. Current limiting should have kicked in, or else a fuse should have blown.

Answer (score 2):

A more likely scenario is that the short circuit damaged the power transistors so they failed short circuit, and they in turn caused the capacitors to fail. If the amp uses discrete power transistors, these will be replaceable. If it's a custom IC or hybrid module, you're less likely to be able to find replacements.

Resistance measurements on the transistor pins (compare with the "good" channel) looking for collector-emitter shorts may help confirm this scenario, and show which transistors need replacing. Or if both channels measure the same, you may be lucky and re-capping will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to recap, I can assume you have the tools to check the entire circuit (DMM, etc).  The only way to really know what went wrong is to start tracing through the circuit.

You may need to get more parts than just the caps - if the transistors and other components were taken down at the same time, there could be quite a few more parts to buy.  Test all components first, get parts when you know exactly what you need to replace.

Otherwise, I'm with Brian D on this!